# When do iOS apps reach the end of main()?

Tags: objective-c, uikit

I am new to Objective-C . We know all Objective-C programs start with the `main` method . Then it should end after some time, but iOS applications keep on running even when they reach the end of that method. Can you please explain?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is because a run loop is created when this line is run:

```
    int retVal = UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, nil);
```

The run loop processes incoming events (button presses, mouse movements, timers, network activity, etc. This loop never terminates. The way the app is terminated is either by the OS or by the `exit()` function which terminates the app from wherever it is called. You should never call the `exit()` function in iOS as the OS should always handle the app termination in the background.

Comment: Technically the end of the main function is *never* reached.  The only way out of the application loop is to terminate the application.

Comment: From the [UIKit docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIKitFunctionReference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/UIApplicationMain): "Even though an integer return type is specified, this function never returns."

Comment: @BergQuester : thanks for your reply . Now i got the concept behind .

Comment: Borrrden and Sebastian are correct, I have updated my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

The line that calls UIApplicationMain sets up a loop that continues running for your whole application. So basically, it's in the middle of the main loop the entire time the application is running. The only time it exits is when the system tells it to quit or the app crashes. If you want to respond to changes such as the app quitting, you should implement the Application Delegate methods. To reiterate, it is very rare when programming for iOS that you will have to modify the main.m file.